# Change Data Type

Tags: custom-field, roll-up-summary, data-types

I have a field in production `number_of_requests__c` type `Number (18, 0)`, the entered data is copied (on save) to another field `number_of_case__c` type `Number (6, 0)` of another related object.

In the main object I have another field "rollup" that sums all the values ​​contained in the `number_of_case__c` (field of the object related). A user is trying to put the value 1000000 in `number_of_requests__c` and the system returns the error `NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE`.

Can I change the `number_of_case` field type from `Number (6, 0)` to `Number (18, 0)` without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can increase the length without losing the data. You might get a warning but you can ignore that.

If you are still concerned then you can export that data in a CSV file and later you can upload those records in case if you find that you did lose some data.

Comment: I can't reload data. This is thought worry

Comment: If you are increasing the size then it won't affect. You may lose the data if you're narrowing the field content length. In your case, you are good to go since 6 < 18.